# Why the paper size is called a fools-cap?

Tags: measuring-units

Usually the sizes are to be measured in any of the units. But to our amazement the paper size is called as FOOL'S CAP. This is not defining any measurement exactly but it throw a vague idea about the exact size of the paper both in length and width. So kindly enlighten me with your thorough knowledge for clearing my long time blur.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Foolscap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foolscap_folio) is a British pre-metric paper size so named for the fool's cap and bells watermark that appeared on sheets of paper of this size beginning in fifteenth century Germany. Usage in England ca. [1700](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=foolscap).

Comment: To my knowledge and experience, this answer is technically correct albeit brief, undeserving of a down vote without comment.

Comment: The linked paragraph says 'unsubstantiated anecdotes' and 'citation needed', so not exactly a brilliant find, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a folk etymology but it isn't. The _citation needed_  on Wikipedia refers to the Rump Parliament and Royal Arms. Added further reference to usage in England rather than just the watermark.

Comment: The Q is "Why"?

Comment: How does my answer not explain that? Imported German paper in  that size with that watermark = name for paper size even when later paper is cheap stuff with no watermark made in England.

Comment: If I remember correctly from my schooldays, foolscap paper was 13 inches by 8 (about 32.5 x 20 cm.).

Comment: @Stan An answer needs to be more than what is a "commonly available reference" as much as the OP needs to show background effort.

Comment: @Kris: I await then your suitably exhaustive answer where you wax eloquent about the philosophical implications of calling a paper size after a watermark.

Comment: @KarlG We would not be expected to wax eloquent on an OT.